# Unable to get element from dropdown menu using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am trying to extract the information from this website: http://reportes.sui.gov.co/fabricaReportes/frameSet.jsp?idreporte=acu_com_150

I am using selenium for that purpose but I have been unable to locate each element of year, department or municipality.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('http://reportes.sui.gov.co/fabricaReportes/frameSet.jsp?idreporte=acu_com_150')
time.sleep(5)

selectYear = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("acu_com_150.agno"))
```

I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: The Website you have provided seems down.

Comment: I can't open this page in web browser.

Comment: Maybe the website is only accessible from certain countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown box you are after its inside an `iframe` and need to switch to `iframe` first in order to access the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://reportes.sui.gov.co/fabricaReportes/frameSet.jsp?idreporte=acu_com_150")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"header")))
select=Select(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,"acu_com_150.agno"))))
select.select_by_value("2018")
```